# how to store uploaded files in secure folder and it can be accessed securely in asp.net core?

Tags: file-upload, asp.net-core, static-files

how to store uploaded files in secure folder and it can be accessed securely in asp.net core? I knew the folder must be outside for www root folder. However, I did some google search still cannot find an  example. Can someone please help me give an example or give me instructions how to setup? Thanks.

I refer to the instructions from ([Serving Static Files Outside of wwwroot in Asp.NET Core 1.0](http://126kr.com/article/6yo92s7gi29)) to setup. 
But it's still available for public access. I would like to only authorized user can access the uploaded files. how to do that? Thanks.

Comment: The authorized users would access the files using your app or directly the filesystem? Do you want to secure your folder, or your APP?

Comment: Connie, you may be able to assist -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51755011/should-i-create-my-folder-for-file-uploads-under-wwwroot-inside-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) The simplest solution which may depend on your server OS and access level, to adjust folder access permissions. To advise on this I would need more details from you.

(2) A better approach I think would be to implement a handler/service that would handle public requests, and if user if authorized then stream the file's content back to the user. Yet again, depending on your server/configuration, might need to refer to (1) also.

(3) Another option is to use a cloud blob storage, where you could set storage to be private and use their API, and issue access tokens for users to access a specific file. Tokens may be set to expire after some time as well.