# Should I create my folder for file uploads under wwwroot inside visual studio?

Tags: c#, iis, file-upload, asp.net-core, windows-server-2012

If I were to follow this [example](https://tahirnaushad.com/2017/08/28/uploaddownload-files-in-asp-net-core-2-0/) file uploads would be stored in the wwwroot file. It is my understanding this file is where you should store static files that will be served to the user. Sure, I want my users to be able to download but is there a filesystem, specific to asp.net core/IIS/Windows Server 2012, that would be best? I'm expecting around 10,000 files max after several years.

I'm planning on creating a folder for the uploaded documents, I'm just unsure of where to place it.

Note: The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129374/how-to-store-uploaded-files-in-secure-folder-and-it-can-be-accessed-securely-in) was not sufficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To the best of my understanding, unless you take special precautions, files under wwwroot can be downloaded freely by users, bots, etc. with no authentication.  If the files are not sensitive in nature, then there is nothing wrong with using wwwroot.

If you want to provide security at the controller level (e.g., a user can only view their own files), then it's probably better to put them elsewhere in the file system.  The path is kind of arbitrary, but the security settings on the folder must be set in such a way that the dotnet process can access it.  You can give Everyone full access, or be more restrictive if you see fit.  This is done directly on the OS of the server, assuming that you have access to it.

Comment: The files are sensitive, so I will be storing them outside wwwroot. Just found the line, "Store them outside of wwwroot and any directory accessible to the static file middleware and..." in the docs that stated that. :| Probably should of read that a more carefully... docs link -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#usefileserver

Comment: If the path is arbitrary then I can just right click project -> Add -> New Folder and store them there or I can create a folder on the server, right? Shouldn't matter?

Comment: Yes, either way will work.  If you are injecting IHostingEnvironment into your service, then you can use `hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath` to get the absolute path of the top level of your file structure as seen in Visual Studio. `hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` gives you the absolute path to wwwroot.

Comment: It would actually be better to keep it out of your project entirely. That way there's no chance of accidentally committing anything to source control, and you can deploy multiple copies of your app (load-balancing scenarios and such) that all read/write from a common directory. You can use your config to specify the directory and then switch that out based on environment as well.

Comment: @ChrisPratt care to leave an answer?

Answer (score 1):

For 2 reasons I would not do that.
1. Keep control and overview. I would create a subfolder and give it the needed rights to create and write uploaded files there.
2. You are then free to change authorization if your requirements ever should change.